# How to return several files for ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Tags: android, android-intent

After passing through the system file manager, the file manager I made is able to return a file when asked (say, by K9 email client) through ACTION_GET_CONTENT with this:

```
Uri uri = SearchOut.getUriFromFile(this, context.getPackageName(), file);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

K9 gets the file normally.

My file manager is also able to share multiple files with this:

```
ArrayList<Uri> urilist = ...
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, urilist);
shareIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Sharing files..."));
```

Then I can open K9 and loads all the files.

So how do I return SEVERAL files to K9 when they are requested through ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

As I wrote above, I know how to send several files with K9, or return 1 file when K9 asks, but I don't know how to return several files when K9 asks. The system file manager does return several files and K9 loads all of them happily.

Comment: `but I don't know how to return several files when K9 asks.` What is happening 'when K9 asks'? What do you mean? How does such a question look like? And who is asked? And what does it have to do with action get content? Your post is quite confusing.

Comment: So you state that K9 uses ACTION_GET_CONTENT and startActivityForResult and the user chooses your app and the user selects several files and now you wanna transfer the uries to K9? Well put them in the return uri in the same way as you would extract them from the intent in onActivityResult when your app used that action.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. By "when K9 asks" I mean the action requested when you press the attachment button. According to K9 devs, it is a standard ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent. This intent is handled by the system in new versions of Android, but my system filemanager allows me to use my filemanager by selecting it in the option "browse files with another app". If I then select 1 file only, it works with the above code. But I don't know how to build an intent for several files, since `intent.setDataAndType` does not accept a list of URIs.

Comment: Yup, `getIntent().getAction()` returns `android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry, but I did not understand your suggestion in your second answer. I tried to build an intent to return it with `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)` using an `ArrayList<Uri>`, `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)`, and `shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, urilist)`, but K9 did not load the files. In other words, I need to build an intent as the first one I wrote, but for several files instead of one.

Comment: Got it to work with ClipData. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `ClipData` (needs API >= 16). Not sure if it is the best way to build the ClipData, though:

```
ClipData clipData = null;
for (Uri u : getSelectedFilesToArrayOfUri()) {
    if (clipData == null)
        clipData = ClipData.newRawUri(null, u);
    else
        clipData.addItem(new ClipData.Item(u));
}
intent.setClipData(clipData);
intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Comment: If there is only one uri you should not use clip data.z

Comment: Yes, that block is only executed for more than 2 uris and API >= 16.